# AMQP connection reset by peer, but celery connected

Tags: python, flask, rabbitmq, celery, amqp

I have a flask app using Celery with RabbitMQ as the broker.

I've followed the instructions in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26986746/how-to-configure-and-run-celery-worker-on-remote-system) to get started.

I have two machines.

Machine A, where RabbitMQ runs, sends tasks to be consumed by celery on Machine B.

My Broker Url and Backend Result Url are the same: `amqp://remote:***@12.345.678.999:5672/remote_host`.

Both machines have copies of the flask app on them. RabbitMQ has been configured so that user remote has all permissions granted ".* .* .*". All the communication between RabbitMQ and Celery works fine when they're both running on localhost on Machine A.

I start celery on Machine B with `celery worker -l info -A app.celery`, and everything looks fine:

```
 -------------- celery@ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX v4.0.0 (latentcall)
---- **** ----- 
--- * ***  * -- Linux-4.4.0-45-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-16.04-    xenial 2016-11-06 18:18:01
-- * - **** --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         app:0x7f5b9dd73d90
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://remote:**@12.345.578.999:5672/remote_host
- ** ---------- .> results:     amqp://
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 1 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
            .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]
  . app.views.task1
  . app.views.task2
  . app.views.task3


[2016-11-06 18:18:01,614: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to amqp://remote:**@12.345.678.999:5672/remote_host
[2016-11-06 18:18:01,627: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2016-11-06 18:18:02,658: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2016-11-06 18:18:02,672: INFO/MainProcess] celery@ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX ready.
```

When I run the app on Machine A and try to send a task through RabbitMQ to Celery, I get `[Errno 104] Connection reset by peer` with the following (partial) stack trace:

```
  File "/home/ubuntu/app/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/abstract_channel.py", line 67, in wait
self.channel_id, allowed_methods, timeout)
  File "/home/ubuntu/app/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 241, in _wait_method
channel, method_sig, args, content = read_timeout(timeout)
  File "/home/ubuntu/app/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 330, in read_timeout
return self.method_reader.read_method()
  File "/home/ubuntu/app/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/method_framing.py", line 189, in read_method
raise m
error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

I also get an AMQP debug statemenet like the following:

```
amqp: DEBUG: Start from server, version: 0.9, properties:    {u'information': u'Licensed under the MPL.  See   http://www.rabbitmq.com/', u'product': u'RabbitMQ', u'copyright':    u'Copyright (C) 2007-2015 Pivotal Software, Inc.', u'capabilities':   

{u'exchange_exchange_bindings': True, u'connection.blocked': True,   u'authentication_failure_close': True, u'basic.nack': True, u'per_consumer_qos': True, u'consumer_priorities': True, u'consumer_cancel_notify': True, u'publisher_confirms': True},

 u'cluster_name': u'rabbit@ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX.ec2.internal', u'platform': u'Erlang/OTP', u'version': u'3.5.7'}, mechanisms: [u'PLAIN', u'AMQPLAIN'], locales: [u'en_US']
```

I've tried looking at rabbitmqctl list_exchanges, list_consumers, list_bindings, but I haven't been able to make much sense out of them.

How can I debug this to figure out why RabbitMQ can't send tasks to Celery?

Comment: I think rabbitmq is not receiving messages from remote. Can try manually sending messages to rabbitmq remotely https://github.com/ChillarAnand/01/blob/master/python/exercise/pika_exp.py ?

Comment: Thanks, @ChillarAnand, will try tomorrow and update you.

Comment: @ABM, Just check my answer. I tried to help you.I don't know my solution will be work for you or not but I followed that steps and it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I also have same requirements, I also followed this [tutorial](http://avilpage.com/2014/11/scaling-celery-sending-tasks-to-remote.html) and It's working fine.

Looks like issue in your broker url, Just try to configure in following way :

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks', backend='amqp',
broker='amqp://username:password@yourIp:5672//')

#Test Celery configuration
@app.task
def test(x, y):
    return x + y
```

And Start worker :

```
celery worker -l info -A app.celery
```

Test it :

```
Python
>>> from app.celery import test
>>> test.delay(3,4)
<AsyncResult: 68480bd4-ebda-4238-87b1-ad896a75a12c>
```

and check your terminal you will get expected output.

**Note:** I don't know it will be work for you or not.
I did this and it's working fine for me.